# satisfy the Euler-Lagrange equation

Tags: optimization, calculus-of-variations

Two circles of unit radius, each normal to the line through their centers are a distance *d* apart.  A soap film is formed between themas shown below; energetic considerations require the filem to assume a shape of minimum surface area.

a) show that for any value of d less than a critical value $d_{c}$, there are two surfaces satisfying the appropriate Euler-Lagrange equation, while for *d > $d_{c}$* there is no surface.  evaluate $d_{c}$ for a typical d < $d_{c}$, sketch the 2 surfaces.  which has the lesser area?

b) show that in a certain range $d_{o}$ < d < $d_{c}$, the minimum surface as given by the Euler-Lagrange equation has an area larger than 2$\pi$, so hat the surface is "metastable"; that is, the surface is stable against small perturbations but not against *arbitrary* perturbation.  evaluate $d_{o}$.

c) what happens when *d* is in creased beyond $d_{c}$?

[Here is an drawing of the surface.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9r2M.jpg)

[Here is what i have so far.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/294Pd.png)

Comment: ok i edited the question with what i have been able to do so far.

Comment: **Please** make the effort to write your development as MathJax. Desciphering handwriting is enough of my job to not wanting to do it in my hobby here.

Comment: haha i understand i will type it up when i get a chance im about to have to get offline for the night.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The free energy of the film is to be minimized by surface area minimization. If we assume that d is along x-axis due to axial-symmetry minimal surface is a surface of revolution given by
$$A[y]=2\pi \int_{x_1}^{x_2} y \sqrt{1+y'^2}\ dx$$
Correspending Euler Lagrange equation
$$\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}-\frac{d}{dx}\bigg(\frac{\partial g}{\partial y'}\bigg)=0$$
where ommiting constants
$$\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}=\sqrt{1+y'^2}$$ 
$$\frac{d}{dx}\bigg(\frac{\partial g}{\partial y'}\bigg)=\frac{d}{dx}\bigg(\frac{y\ y'}{\sqrt{1+y'^2}}\bigg)=\frac{y'^2}{\sqrt{1+y'^2}}+\frac{y''}{\sqrt{1+y'^2}}-\frac{y\ y'^2\ y''}{\big(\sqrt{1+y'^2}\big)^3}$$
If you replace the partials and collect the terms you have
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+y'^2}}-\frac{y\ y''}{\big(\sqrt{1+y'^2}\big)^3}=0$$
Further simplification by multiplying $y'$ and collecting terms
$$\frac{y'}{\sqrt{1+y'^2}}-\frac{y\ y'\  y''}{\big(\sqrt{1+y'^2}\big)^3}=\frac{d}{dx}\bigg(\frac{y}{\sqrt{1+y'^2}}\bigg)=0$$
The minimization problem reduces to find a solution to a first-order differential equation solution.
$$\frac{y}{\sqrt{1+y'^2}}=\alpha$$
which can be recast as
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\sqrt{\frac{y^2}{\alpha^2}-1}$$
and separation of variables
$$\int dx=\int \frac{dy}{\sqrt{\frac{y^2}{\alpha^2}-1}}$$
Necessary substitution as $y=\alpha\ \cosh t$ and
$$\int dx=\alpha \int dt\Rightarrow x+\beta=\alpha\ t$$
and by back-substitution
$$y=\alpha \cosh \frac{x+\beta}{\alpha}$$

The boundary conditions must be integrated to the solution. To be able to use symmetry I assume origin lies in the middle of length d. The curve must pass through points $(\frac{-d}{2},1)$ and $(\frac{d}{2},1)$. Due to symmetry we can say that $\beta=0$. The following condition must be satisfied
$$1=\alpha \cosh \frac{d}{2\alpha}$$
I guess from this point you can analyze required points.

Comment: @vonbrand Thanks for correction

Answer (score 2):

Here's a very helpful link which I believe answers this question:

http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-086-mathematical-methods-for-engineers-ii-spring-2006/readings/am72.pdf

Comment: yes, looks helpful