# Calculus of Variations - Circles with soapy membrane problem

Tags: multivariable-calculus, calculus-of-variations, mathematical-physics

Calculus of variations is coming to me at a crawl pace.  Here is a problem on my agenda that I wanted to get solved, but am not quite sure how to approach.  I've been thinking about it for a while now.  I figured everybody would appreciate a scanned image instead of a declaration of text, so here is a scanned image.

I'll continue to work the problem for the next several hours or so alongside the others I wanted to complete, but as always, if somebody knows a valid solution using calculus of variations it would sure help a bunch since this specific problem is only study material.

[image: Soap Membrane]

Comment: Does this have something to do with: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/346027/satisfy-the-euler-lagrange-equation perhaps?